# Escaping double quotes in perl in Linux

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

Its not letting me reply to comment so editing here, using Linux as OS.
I am using the undermentioned to get tickets created, but -k parameter, duplication parameter gets the message in " " and if there are "" in the message, then these parameters gets messed up and messages dont get forwarded. 
How to escape these double quotes in -k parameter so that it goes through? 
Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Getopt::Std;



# declare the perl command line flags/options we want to allow


# Define the environment

   my %option=();

   my $SEND_OUTPUT = "" ;

   my $MODE = "Prod" ;

   my $SENDEVENT_LOG = "";

   my $DATE = "" ;

   my $SEND_EVENT = "";

   my $SEND_OUTPUT_LOG = "" ;

   my $DSOM_SEV = "" ;

getopts("q:a:n:p:s:k:c:m:t:y:z:", \%option);


# Define the environment



       if ( $MODE =~ m/Prod/i ) {

            $SENDEVENT_LOG="/var/opt/SendEvent/log/SendEvent.log";

 }



 if ( $MODE =~ m/Dev/i ) {



     $SENDEVENT_LOG="/var/opt/SendEvent/log/SendEvent.Dev.log";



 }   

# Define time stamp



       my $DATE=`date +%Y:%m:%d:\%T`; chomp $DATE ; my $TIME=`date +%T`; chomp $TIME; my $NOW=$DATE." ";





# Open Logfile and define the Date Variable




       open ( LOGFILE, ">>${SENDEVENT_LOG}" ) or die ("Cannot open SendEvent log file ");




# test for the existence of the options on the command line.

# in a normal program you'd do more than just print these.




print LOGFILE "$DATE *******************************************************************\n";

print LOGFILE "\n$DATE New Instance of SendEvent initiated\n" ;

print LOGFILE "$DATE Examine the input arguments below to validate this instance of SendEvent\n\n" ;



       print "\n\n" ;



       if ( $option{q} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -q $option{q}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -q **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{a} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -a $option{a}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -a **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{n} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -n $option{n}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -n **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{p} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -p $option{p}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -p **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{s} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -s $option{s}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -s **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{k} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -k $option{k}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -k **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{c} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -c $option{c}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -c **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{m} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -m $option{m}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -m **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{t} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -t $option{t}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -t **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{y} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -y $option{y}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -y **** value missing *****\n" }

       if ( $option{z} ) { print LOGFILE "$DATE -z $option{z}\n" } else { print LOGFILE "$DATE -z **** value missing *****\n" }



       # other things found on the command line

       print LOGFILE "$DATE Other things found on the command line:\n" if $ARGV[0];

       foreach (@ARGV)

       {

         print LOGFILE "$DATE $_\n";

       }


     my $TOOL          =  "$option{q}"  ;

     my $MSG_APPL      =  "$option{a}"  ;

     my $MSG_NODE_NAME =  "$option{n}"  ;

     my $ESM_PROFILE   =  "$option{p}"  ;

     my $MSG_SEV       =  "$option{s}"  ;

     my $DEDUPLICATION =  "$option{k}"  ;

     my $MANAGEMENT_ID =  "$option{c}"  ;

     my $LONG_TEXT     =  "$option{m}"  ;

     my $SHORT_TEXT    =  "$option{t}"  ;

     my $DEFAULT_Q     =  "$option{y}"  ;

     my $ACCOUNT       =  "$option{z}"  ;



# Translate OpenView Severity to DSOM Severity



#                    OpenView Sev               DSOM Sev



     if ( $MSG_SEV =~ m/Critical/i ) { $DSOM_SEV = "FATAL"    }

     if ( $MSG_SEV =~ m/Major/i    ) { $DSOM_SEV = "CRITICAL" }

     if ( $MSG_SEV =~ m/Minor/i    ) { $DSOM_SEV = "MINOR"    }

     if ( $MSG_SEV =~ m/Warning/i  ) { $DSOM_SEV = "WARNING"  }

     if ( $MSG_SEV =~ m/Normal/i   ) { $DSOM_SEV = "HARMLESS" }



     print LOGFILE "\n$DATE Translating Openview Severity to DSOM Severity, $MSG_SEV => $DSOM_SEV\n\n" ;


    $SEND_OUTPUT_LOG = "/opt/SendEvent/dist/SendEvent/SendEvent send -q \"$TOOL\" -a \"$MSG_APPL\" -n \"$MSG_NODE_NAME\" -p \"$ESM_PROFILE\" -s \"$DSOM_SEV\" -k \"$DEDUPLICATION\" -c \"$MANAGEMENT_ID\" -m \"$LONG_TEXT\" -t \"ABC $SHORT_TEXT\" -z \"ABC\"  -y \"$DEFAULT_Q\"" ;



    $SEND_EVENT=`/opt/SendEvent/dist/SendEvent/SendEvent send -q "$TOOL" -a "$MSG_APPL" -n "$MSG_NODE_NAME" -p "$ESM_PROFILE" -s "$DSOM_SEV" -k "$DEDUPLICATION" -c "$MANAGEMENT_ID" -m "$LONG_TEXT" -t "ABC $SHORT_TEXT" -z "ABC" -y \"$DEFAULT_Q\"`  ;


    print LOGFILE "$DATE \n$SEND_EVENT\n\n" ; 



    print LOGFILE "$DATE $SEND_OUTPUT_LOG\n\n" ;
```

Comment: What OS do you run?

Comment: you are getting a lot of votes to close for unclarity about what you are asking.  This is probably because there's so much code there it makes it hard to find the part you are actually talking about.  Try to narrow down the code you post to what is necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the easiest way to quote a variable for shell interpolation is to:

1. enclose it in `''`
2. replace any `'` with `'"'"'`

So replace

```
$SEND_EVENT=`/opt/SendEvent/dist/SendEvent/SendEvent send -q "$TOOL" -a "$MSG_APPL" -n "$MSG_NODE_NAME" -p "$ESM_PROFILE" -s "$DSOM_SEV" -k "$DEDUPLICATION" -c "$MANAGEMENT_ID" -m "$LONG_TEXT" -t "ABC $SHORT_TEXT" -z "ABC" -y \"$DEFAULT_Q\"`  ;
```

with

```
(my $quoted_DEDUPLICATION = $DEDUPLICATION) =~ s/'/'"'"'/g;
$SEND_EVENT=`/opt/SendEvent/dist/SendEvent/SendEvent send -q "$TOOL" -a "$MSG_APPL" -n "$MSG_NODE_NAME" -p "$ESM_PROFILE" -s "$DSOM_SEV" -k '$quoted_DEDUPLICATION' -c "$MANAGEMENT_ID" -m "$LONG_TEXT" -t "ABC $SHORT_TEXT" -z "ABC" -y \"$DEFAULT_Q\"`  ;
```

(and do the same for all your other parameters).

Alternatively, use IPC::System::Simple::capturex and pass all the arguments in an array.